# Measuring frequency of 3-wire 12V fan on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, frequency

I am using a PC 12V fan (40x40mm), which I control speed with voltage (with adjustable power supply). I would like to measure the frequency of the fan with Arduino and read it on serial monitor.

I've googled over some results and I came across `pulseIn()`, which I don't quite understand. I've also used this code, which I found [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print), but it doesn't work for me. I've added `serial.print` and delay line.

My output of this program is: "0000000" etc. and nothing else.

My goal is to set the frequency of the fan to around 50-500 Hz somewhere.

```
int pin = 7;
unsigned long duration;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  duration = pulseIn(pin, HIGH);
  Serial.print(duration);
  delay(1);
}
```

My schematics:

[image]

Comment: Edited. I hope it helps. I power supply arduino through USB cable from PC and instead of battery I just use variable bench power supply.

Comment: Thanks. Try changing `pinMode(pin, INPUT);` to `pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP);` and tell us what happens. If it works, I'll write an answer explaining why.

Comment: @MarkSmith: Yes and no. But this is a step further for sure.
Yes: I do get values from arduino, but not some kind of useful.
No: As I raise the voltage (and raise the turning speed) the lower values I get by reading the input. At about 4.85V I got the value of 2800, but at voltage 2.48V I get value of 5740 (about). How can I get RPMs from this?

Comment: You should **not** connect the ground wire to the other side of the potentiometer! That will just waste energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pulseIn` measures the duration of a high pulse on the pin.  The [reference page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.PulseIn) explains it as well as I ever could.  If there is a specific thing you don't understand from it, please ask.  However, I don't think it will achieve what you want.

The circuitry in the fan connects the third (yellow?) wire to ground twice per revolution of the fan.  To make this into a "pulse" you need to pull the pin high.  Twice per revolution, the fan will pull it low.

What you now have is a signal which, for every revolution of the fan, goes `HIGH`, `LOW`, `HIGH`, `LOW`.  We want to measure the time from one rising edge to the next.  This is the time for half a rotation of the fan.

Here's some untested code:

```
// Wait for signal to go low
while (HIGH==digitalRead(pin)) { /* Do nothing */ }

// Start timing
unsigned long start_time = micros();

// Wait for signal to go high and low again
while (LOW==digitalRead(pin)) { /* Do nothing */ }
while (HIGH==digitalRead(pin)) { /* Do nothing */ }

// Stop timing
unsigned long end_time = micros();

// How long did that take?
unsigned long duration  = end_time - start_time;
```

That code can be improved in various ways but I hope it will let you understand what's going on.

That tells us how LONG half a cycle takes.  You can easily find how long a whole cycle would take -- double it.  If you want the frequency in revolutions-per-minute, you need to work out how many whole cycles you can get in a minute, which is the same as the number of half-cycles in half a minute:

```
unsigned long rpm = 30000000L / duration;
```